# Buggy multi-select element on iPhone 5S with iOS 7

Tags: html, ios, iphone, cross-browser

I'm testing a multi-select box on iPhone 5S iOS 7 -- on Browserstack's "real devices" -- but it seems buggy and wanted to know if this is a known issue, and if there's a workaround.

**Buggy behaviour 1** Safari removes the last `option` a user has selected after choosing `done`, moving to the next `>` input field (if there is one), or hitting a `submit` button (if there is one).

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Saxophone">Saxophone</option>
    <option value="Flute">Flute</option>
    <option value="Clarinet">Clarinet</option>
</selct>
```

So, before making any selections the dropdown menu displays "0 Items"; if you were to select Saxophone from the above list, it would display "Saxophone", but then when you hit `Done` Saxophone is deselected and it displays "0 Items" again. If you were to select Saxophone then Flute, it would display "2 Items", but then when you hit `Done` it would deselect Flute and display only "Saxophone". And just for the FUN of all this, if you were to select Saxophone, Flute and lastly Clarinet, then hit `Done`, it would deselect Clarinet and display "2 Items".

**Note:** This occurs with or without the `optgroup`'s as described below.

**Buggy behaviour 2**: Safari crashes when using an `optgroup` when the select box is selected. A workaround I've found is placing a `disabled` `option` before the first `optgroup`.

So, this crashes:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Private">
        <option value="Saxophone">Saxophone</option>
        <option value="Flute">Flute</option>
        <option value="Clarinet">Clarinet</option>
    </optgroup>
</selct>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option disabled value="choose"></option>
    <optgroup label="Private">
        <option value="Saxophone">Saxophone</option>
        <option value="Flute">Flute</option>
        <option value="Clarinet">Clarinet</option>
    </optgroup>
</selct>
```

I'm also wondering if anybody has seen this on other iOS versions/devices.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting work-around, I've been testing on 9.3.4. It is unfortunate that another iOS bug allows the user to pick the additional 'disabled' option that is part of the work-around. That shouldn't be possible! I guess it's better than outright crashing...